# Unable to display database table entries in laravel

Tags: database, laravel, sqlite

I am unable to retrieve any table data, it just displays the text 'There are no upcoming events' as if my entries are 0 but tinker shows otherwise.

Can anyone see any errors in this or offer any suggestions? It was working not too long ago, I don't know what happened and for the life of me can not figure it out. I am using laravel and sqlite.

Events Controller:

```
use App\EventEntry;


class EventsController extends Controller
{
    public function displayEvent()

    {
        $entries = EventEntry::get();
        return view('eventdisplay', ['entries' => $entries]);

    }
```

EventEntry.php:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EventEntry extends Model
{

}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('events', 'EventsController@displayEvent')->name('displayEvent');
```

events.blade.php:

```
<div>@include('eventdisplay')</div>
```

eventdisplay.blade.php:

```
<h1>Events</h1>

    @if($entries->count() == 0)
    <div>
    <p>There are no upcoming events.</p>
</div>
@else ...
```

Migration:

```
Schema::create('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('address');
    $table->string('description');
    $table->dateTime('event_date');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

}

tinker:

```
>>> DB::table('events')->get();
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#761
     all: [
       {#759
         +"id": "1",
         +"title": "Spring Festival",
         +"address": "demo",
         +"description": "lorem",
         +"event_date": "2018-02-23 09:00:00",
         +"created_at": null,
         +"updated_at": null,
       },
       {#758
         +"id": "2",
         +"title": "International Festival",
         +"address": "demo",
         +"description": "lorem",
         +"event_date": "2018-02-28 18:00:00",
         +"created_at": null,
         +"updated_at": null,
       },
     ],
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name your Model 'Event', or use `$table` property to override the table name as in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent) -
 **Table Names** section:

> Note that we did not tell Eloquent which table to use for our Flight model. By convention, the "snake case", plural name of the class will be used as the table name unless another name is explicitly specified. So, in this case, Eloquent will assume the Flight model stores records in the  flights table. You may specify a custom table by defining a table property on your model:

Comment: You are a star thank you! Once I read what you put I remembered reading that in the docs. I feel a little silly now. Much appreciated!